# How to select multiple dates in DatePicker Dialog?

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

Im done to pick single date in DatePickerDialog but now i need to choose and display multiple date in DatePickerDialog .

Here my java code,

```
  private void DatePicker_new() {
        // Get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.TimePickerTheme,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                String monthString = String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1);
                if (monthString.length() == 1) {
                    monthString = "0" + monthString;
                }
                Tv_endate_response.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + monthString + "-" + year);

            }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);

    }
```

Comment: With native `DatePickerDialog` you can't . You need to select one by one . If you want to select a date range then you better look for custom implementation of `DatePicker`(Usually a third party library).

Comment: Can you mention best multiple date selecter library. @ADM

Comment: Google it yourself . [Here](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker) is one .

Comment: @ADM above one is used to choose from start to end date. i need randam choose

Comment: This can be very simple if you just put two `DatePicker` widgets in a `AlertDialog` . Look for Custom alert dialog tutorial .